# How do you fix the Home and End keys producing 'H' and 'F'?

Tags: terminal, environment-variables

I recently was doing some Vim editing and noticed the behavior was very different for two important keys.

The only difference I made was I started bash using:

```
env -i bash --init-script ~/.bashrc.custom.sh
```

I use <kbd>home</kbd>, <kbd>end</kbd> to move the cursor around in `vim`.

But instead of <kbd>home</kbd>, <kbd>end</kbd> moving the cursor... pressing these keys would enter `vim`'s insert mode and output 'H' and 'F' characters.

I want the old behavior.

When I start `bash` normally I get the old behavior.

**How do you fix the <kbd>home</kbd>, <kbd>end</kbd> keys producing 'H' and 'F'?**

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure the environment variable `TERM` is set. For example set the environment variable from `bash` via `export TERM=xterm` THEN open `vim`. Once in `vim` you can check that it worked by doing `set term`.**

---

Apparently `vim` checks the environment variable `TERM` to decide what how to handle terminal control characters (more info on `vim` handling terminal control characters open `vim` help by doing `vim` command `help term`).

I was missing the `TERM` variable, `vim` would use the default and `set term=ansi`.

So for my situation I made sure set the `TERM` environment variable was set (in my ~/.bashrc.custom.sh).

I set the value of `export TERM=xterm`.

Now when I open `vim` the value of `set term` is `xterm` and I get the expected behavior from <kbd>home</kbd>, <kbd>end</kbd>.

Comment: actually, you should export `TERM` to whatever terminal you are really using (or even better, never delete the TERM variable to begin with) . always using `xterm` might cause weird behaviour.

Comment: Always using `xterm` means the weird behaviour is, at least, expected